# Xcode 14 giving build error for flurry sdk

Tags: xcode, xcode14

After updating to xcode 14 I'm getting build error

```
error build: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_Flurry
error build: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlurrySessionBuilder
```

I tried cleaning pods and reinstalling pods and also I tried adding `libFlurry_11.2.1.a` in build phases, it didn't work.

Platform target in pods is '12.1' and for flurry below command is used

```
pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK', '~> 11.2.0'
```

Comment: Can you please share what solution you applied.. I am facing same issue..Please reply

Comment: @Kalyani I didn't solution I reverted back to xcode older version

Answer (score 4):

I had to contact support but for me this worked:

```
pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK', '~> 12.1.1'
```

and the "startSession" has changed to:

```
Flurry.startSession(apiKey: "***", sessionBuilder: FlurrySessionBuilder.init()
        .build(crashReportingEnabled: true)
        .build(logLevel: .all))
```

PS: Your "startSession" might be different. It depends on what you need.